# Python error 'integer is required'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following code

```
# simpleSerialSend.py
import sys
import serial
import time
PORT = 'COM4' # The port my Arduino is on, on my WinXP box.

def main(val=5):
    # Open a connection to the serial port.  This will reset the Arduino, and
    # make the LED flash once:
    ser = serial.Serial(PORT)

    # Must given Arduino time to rest.
    # Any time less than this does not seem to work...
    time.sleep(1.5)

    # Now we can start sending data to it:
    written = ser.write(val)
    ser.close()
    print ("Bytes Written to port:", written)
    print ("Value written to port: '%s'"%val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv
    try:
        main(args[1])
    except IndexError:
        main()
```

and I am kinda new to python.
So the error i get is like in the description said integer required. 
I run it in my cmd with the following rule:  c:\pyModules\simpleSerialSend.py 5
It is working fine only i get the error. What the code does is sending a variable to my arduino so a light goes blinking. The code of the arduino is correct.

Comment: your question would be easier to read if you condensed your code by removing the blank line between every single statement. Also, your indentation is broken. It's hard to tell how much code belongs in `main`.

Comment: try change `main(args[1])` to `main(int(args[1]))`

Comment: When you get an error in Python it's best to paste the *entire* traceback, as it often tells exactly what and where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are coming in as `str`. So, the solution to your problem is actually to just convert the string to `int`

```
main(int(args[1]))  # assuming args[1] is a parsable numeric string
```

Also, maybe take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).